Validate spread of simulated rates under the LMM
Looking for a way to validate the spread of simulated forward rates from the LMM model. Test Log-Normality for LIBOR forward rates under the Libor Market Model this post suggests using the simulated rates to price caplets and that the price should be correct to within 2/3 standard errors.
So suppose we have 100 simulated discount curves. We then use these discount curves and the market quoted vol to price a cap and compare these 100 cap prices to the cap price implied by the yield curve and market quoted vol? If the market price is within 2 or 3 SEs of the average price implied by the simulations then we are good? Is this how to do it or have I misunderstood?
Thanks
